# why is passing a large string as return type bad for performance reasons?

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I am developing a feature that gets data and stores in a file in default directory where in at the end of it, we need to pass data from the file in the form of some data structure.

At this point, its decided to not use `string array` as passing back a data of more than 4mb would cost us the performance. But while saying this, I don't understand how will this cost us the performance?

`Hashmap` also uses a `array` underneath and thats what we are going forward with.

Comment: It has more to do with how you construct the 4mb string and how callers of your code will use the returned value. Returning 4mb string is not necessarily a bad design.

Comment: I think you would pass the reference to the array (which in the end also stores just references to Strings), so I do not see a problem there. Are you sure this is your performance problem?

Comment: Passing or returning a single variable in Java will always cost you copying one (1) machine word for the reference (regardless of its size).  Java has no copy semantics.  Unless you create an explicit copy of the structure, there won't be any draconian cost.  Of course, if you don't need all of the data, you shouldn't create the structure (whatever structure) in the first place.

Comment: Just to make sure: this is in-JVM method return, not RMI/EJB/distributed computing ... ?

Comment: I think you'll find [this article helpful](http://www.coderanch.com/t/478502/Performance/java/store-huge-string-array-list) for String Array performance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't returning a potentially large result, the performance issue stems from *producing* a large result the caller may actually doesn't really need.

An example is the Class.getResource() family of calls. Imagine that instead of an URL or a Stream they were designed to return a byte[] with the actual data. Now for a multimedia application that has a lot of media resources, this would be deadly; for simply getting the header information of a media resource, the call would actually result in the entire resource being pulled into memory, a few of the first KB would be actually used and the remainder would be thrown away. Its clear that this is wasteful of memory and processing time.

So a large result *may* lead to doing a lot of work in vain.

Answer (score 0):

In general I wouldn't say that passing large strings should be performance-critical. As soon as the data is stored in your working memory, passing it shouldn't be tnoticeable. Indeed, reading 4 mb of data from a hard disk will be an I/O-intensive task, probably causing a noticeable GUI-freeze (at least when not using an async method for that).